# Cloned elements' events corresponding to all elements in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I successfully cloned my table rows, which has values retrieved from database. However I have few issues with it.I used class for all the elements as clone will duplicate IDs.No the problem raises because it unable to target each element  uniquely. WHat's the way to do make each element / row unique here?

How the functions work:

- When first select box selected, item for that selected id would appear in the next column.Followed by price textbox and quantity textbox. WHen both are filled up, last textbox for total amount would automatically appear.

Issues with the cloning are:
* WHen select box selected from the first/original row, all cloned items are updated with the value.Same goes for amount textbox and vise-versa.

My script:

```
<script>
  var harga;
  var qty;

  $("input[name^=harga]").on("keyup", function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    console.log($(this).val());
    harga = $(this).val();
  });

  $(".qty").on("keyup", function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
    qty = $(this).val();
    var amount = harga * qty;
    $(".amount").val(amount);
  });

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sub_item").hide();
    $('.gr').change(function () {
      var gr_id = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
      console.log(gr_id);
      var agency_id = '<?php echo $_SESSION['
      agency_id
      '];?>';
      /*show branch for selected department starts*/
      var data;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: s_path + "get-item.php?group=" + gr_id + "&agency=" + agency_id, //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
          $(".sub_item").show();
          $(".it_id").empty();
          for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $(".it_id").append("<option value='" + data[i].item_id + "'>" + data[i].item_name + "</option>");
          }
          if (data.length == "") {
            $(".it_id").append("<option>No items found</option>");
          }
          console.log(data);
        }});//end success
      /*show branch ends*/
    });
  });

  $("#more_items").on("click", function () {
    alert("Hi");
    $(".clone_this").clone(true, true).insertBefore("#last_e");
  });

  $(function () {
    $("#hide1").hide();
    $("#hide2").hide();
    $("#hide3").hide();
    $('#faktor').change(function () {
      var val = $(this).val();
      //alert($(this).val());
      if ($.trim(val) == 1) {
        $("#hide1").show();
      } else {
        $("#hide1").hide();
      }
    });

    $('#insurance').change(function () {
      $("#hide2").show();
      var val = $(this).val();
      //alert($(this).val());
      if ($.trim(val) == 1) {
        $("#hide2").show();
      } else {
        $("#hide2").hide();
      }
    });

    $('#bon').change(function () {
      $("#hide3").show();
      var val = $(this).val();
      //alert($(this).val());
      if ($.trim(val) == 1) {
        $("#hide3").show();
      } else {
        $("#hide3").hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Form

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="submit_item">
    <input type="text" name="contract_id" value="" id="contract_id2"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Group Item</th>
            <th>Nama Item</th>
            <th>Harga</th>
            <th>Kuantiti</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="clone_this">
            <td>
                <select name='group' style="width:80px;" class="gr">
                    <option>Choose group</option>
                    <?php
                        $group = $agency->show_all_group();
                        foreach ($group as $k => $v) {
                            $i = 0;
                            $i++;
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $v['group_id'] ?>"><?php echo $v['group_name'] ?></option>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="sub_item">
                <select name='item' style="width:100px;" class="it_id">

                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="harga_<?php echo $i; ?>[]" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="" class="harga"/></td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' size='2' value="" name='qty[]' class='qty'/>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" class="amount" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="last_e">
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" id="item_s"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Add more items" id="more_items"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: see the first select in work - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j3t4r655/1/ - the `agency_id` and ajax url and data changed to work with jsfiddle

Comment: @ArunPJohny, checked the fiddle, its partially working. The select boxes ok, the amount changes for all rows when one is changed. Next after adding say 3 threee rows then you click again ad more ,it adds another 3 rows! Can you help solve this two as well?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j3t4r655/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need find the relative elements to update so

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#submit_item').on('keyup', '.qty, .harga', function () {
        var $tr= $(this).closest('tr');

        $tr.find('.amount').val($tr.find('.harga').val() * $tr.find('.qty').val() || 0)
    })

    $(".sub_item").hide();
    $('#submit_item').on('change', '.gr', function () {

        var $this = $(this),
            $tr = $this.closest('tr'),
            gr_id = $this.find('option:selected').val(),
            $subitem = $tr.find('.sub_item'),
            $it_id = $tr.find('.it_id');

        var agency_id = '<?php echo $_SESSION['agency_id'];?>';

        /*show branch for selected department starts*/
        var data;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: s_path+"get-item.php?group="+gr_id+"&agency="+agency_id, //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                $subitem.show();
                $it_id.empty();
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $it_id.append("<option value='" + data[i].item_id + "'>" + data[i].item_name + "</option>");
                }
                if (data.length == "") {
                    $it_id.append("<option>No items found</option>");
                }

                console.log(data);
            }
        }); //end success

        /*show branch ends*/
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j3t4r655/)